# Rails Devise confirmable for some users but not others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails app that is using Devise.  Is it possible to have some users confirmable and others not?

The users table has a boolean field called admin.

We add the admin users programmatically using Mule and rest (so we know the email addresses are correct).

The other types of users are self registering and admin is false.

We want the self registering people to get a confirmation email but not the admin users.

UPDATE1

I create the user in the employee.rb file.  I changed the code to this:

```
  before_create :create_user

protected
def create_user
  self.user = User.create({ :email => self.email, :password => '123456', :admin => true  })
  user.skip_confirmation!
  return user.save

end
```

This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding your admins you can call `skip_confirmation!` on the user object - before it's being saved. This will prohibit the confirmation process.